# how do we grab a specific information like the name from this?

Tags: python

I'm looking at this example and I want to figure out how can I search up a name instead of the ID, then display all the information for the name? For example if it has the ID of 1, name: Bob, department: sales, and job title: manager. If we search up "Bob", everything will display. Sorry this is long.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, ID, department, job_title):
        self.__name = name
        self.__ID = ID
        self.__dept = department
        self.__job = job_title

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_department(self, department):
        self.__dept = department

    def set_job_title(self, job_title):
        self.__job = job_title

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_ID_number(self):
        return self.__ID

    def get_department(self):
        return self.__dept

    def get_job_title(self):
        return self.__job

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Name: ' + self.__name + '\n' + \
               'ID Number: ' + str(self.__ID) + '\n' + \
               'Department: ' + self.__dept + '\n' + \
               'Job Title: ' + self.__job
```

```
import pickle

def pickle_it(employees):
    # Open file in binary write mode
    output_file = open('employees.dat', 'wb')
    # Write the data to the file
    pickle.dump(employees, output_file)
    # Close the file
    output_file.close()

def unpickle_it():
    try:
        # Attempt to open file in binary read mode
        input_file = open('employees.dat', 'rb')
    except IOError:
        # If the file doesn't exist, then create it by opening using write
        # mode.  Then just close and reopen in binary read mode.
        file = open('employees.dat', 'wb')
        file.close()
        input_file = open('employees.dat', 'rb')

    # Load the employees dictionary or create an empty dictionary if file is
    # empty
    try:
        employees = pickle.load(input_file)
    except:
        employees = {}

    # Close the file
    input_file.close()

    # Return the employees dictionary
    return employees
```

```
import menu_choices
import save_load_dict

# Global constants for menu choices
LOOK_UP = 1
ADD = 2
CHANGE = 3
DELETE = 4
QUIT = 5

def main():
    employees = save_load_dict.unpickle_it()

    choice = menu_choices.get_menu_choice()

    while choice != QUIT:
        if choice == LOOK_UP:
            menu_choices.look_up(employees)
        elif choice == ADD:
            menu_choices.add(employees)
        elif choice == CHANGE:
            menu_choices.change(employees)
        elif choice == DELETE:
            menu_choices.delete(employees)

        choice = menu_choices.get_menu_choice()

    save_load_dict.pickle_it(employees)

main()
```

```
import employee_class

# Global constants for menu choices
LOOK_UP = 1
ADD = 2
CHANGE = 3
DELETE = 4
QUIT = 5

def get_menu_choice():

    print('\n\033[4m' + 'Employee Directory' + '\033[0m')
    print('1. Look up an employee')
    print('2. Add a new employee')
    print('3. Edit an employee\'s information')
    print('4. Delete an employee')
    print('5. Quit\n')

    # Get the user's choice.
    choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))

    # Validate the choice.
    while choice < LOOK_UP or choice > QUIT:
        choice = int(input('Enter a valid choice: '))

    # return the user's choice.
    return choice

# The look_up function looks up an employee and displays their information.
def look_up(employees):
    # Get a name to look up.
    ID = input('Enter an employee ID number: ')

    # Look it up in the dictionary.
    if ID in employees:
        print(employees[ID])
    else:
        print('That ID number is not found.')

# The add function adds a new entry into the dictionary.
def add(employees):
    # Get employee information.
    name = input('Enter the employee\'s name: ')
    ID = input('Enter the employee\'s ID number: ')
    department = input('Enter the employee\'s department: ')
    job_title = input('Enter the employee\'s job title: ')

    # If the name does not exist, add it.
    if ID not in employees:
        employees[ID] = employee_class.Employee(name, ID, department, \
                                                job_title)
    else:
        print('An entry with that ID number already exists.')
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to take into account that two employees could have the same name. The following code (adapted from your existing `look_up` function) will return all the employees with the name specified, or a message that there are no employees with that name :

```
# The look_up function looks up an employee by name and displays their information.
def look_up_by_name(employees):
    # Get a name to look up.
    name = input('Enter an employee Name: ')

    matches = [emp for emp in employees if emp['name'] == name]

    if len(matches) == 0:
        print('No employees with name "{}" found'.format(name))
    else:
        for m in matches:
            print(m)
```

Comment: sorry i just edited the question and the code. there was another save_load_dict too

Comment: Here, `emp in employees` will iterate on IDs (keys) and hence `emp['name']` will throw an error. You need `emp in employees.values()`

Comment: it gave an error: TypeError: 'Employee' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I reverted to my original answer. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your question heading asks for how to search using email while the `class Employee` has no `email` attribute.
2. To search using other attribute like `Name`:

   Though the code snippets you pasted doesn't define what `employees` object is, it's a `dict` mapping between id and corresponding `Employee` object.
   If you only need to search by name, you can make the employees dictionary as a mapping between `Name` and `Employee` objects (list, as multiple employee can have same name).

   If you need a more dynamic solution that lets you search by just about anything, then you need to match with all attributes of each `Employee` object. And also will need to take care of case insensitivity in search.

```py
def look_up(employees):
    # Get any searchtext to lookup
    searchtext = input('Enter search query to lookup')
    matches = [emp for emp in employees.values()
               if searchtext.lower() in [
                   emp.get_name().lower(),
                   emp.get_ID_number(),        # Add .lower() if needed 
                   emp.get_department().lower(), #.lower() for case insensitive match
                   emp.get_job_title().lower()
                ]
               ]
    if not matches:
        print(f'No employee matches any attribute for searchtext {searchtext}')
        return None
    # If there are valid matches
    print(matches)
```

Eliminate any of the above fields if not needed.

You can go more crazier in terms of matching the string with partial matches like doing `searchtext in candidate for candidate in [emp.<some_attributes>,..]` or use levenshtein distance.